# Why are these two anonymous types not the same?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, roslyn, anonymous-types, ef-core-2.0

Can anyone tell me why these two anonymous types are not the same?

```
{Name = "<>f__AnonymousType0`6" FullName = "<>f__AnonymousType0`6[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}

{Name = "<>f__AnonymousType0#1`6" FullName = "<>f__AnonymousType0#1`6[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}
```

CLARIFICATION: (I don't know if it's important but one anonymous type has a # symbol. oh, #01)

I have these two pieces of code. In the same class (assembly). One returns one of the anonymous types above and the other return the other one. However, both are evaluating the same expression.

I've done the comparisons below (some just to see the result even though some should correctly return false). But, they all return false. (I may have left out some that I've tried)

ms              returns one of the anonymous types.
resultOfSelect returns the other anonymous type.

Note: methodArgumentStringContainingSelectStatement in second piece of code contains the same expression as a string.

---

'ms == resultOfSelect'

'ms.GetType() == resultOfSelect'

'ms.GetType().Equals(resultOfSelect.GetType())'

'ms.GetType() == resultOfSelect.GetType()'

### And others. All False

resultOfSelect debugView is:

{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType0#1>}

ms debugView is:

{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType0>}

1st statement:

```
   ' var ms =     (instanceContainingSelectMethod as IQueryable<Emar>).Select( nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany => new { Schedule = nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.Category.Substring(0, 1), Category = "0" + nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.Category.Substring(1), Description = "", Year = nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.Month.Year, Time = nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.Actual_Time, Units = ((nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.PurchDate ?? nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.InServiceDate).Value.Year == nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.Month.Year)
? (nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.SoldDate != null)
    ? (nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.SoldDate.Value.Year == nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.Month.Year)
        ? (((12d - ((double)((nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.PurchDate != null)
            ? (System.DateTime?)nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.PurchDate.Value
            : nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.InServiceDate).Value.Month)) + 1d) - (12d - ((12d - ((double)nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.SoldDate.Value.Month)) + 1d))) / 12d
        : ((12d - ((double)(nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.PurchDate ?? nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.InServiceDate).Value.Month)) + 1d) / 12d
    : ((12d - ((double)(nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.PurchDate ?? nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.InServiceDate).Value.Month)) + 1d) / 12d
: (nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.SoldDate != null)
    ? (nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.SoldDate.Value.Year == nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.Month.Year)
        ? (12d - ((12d - ((double)nextEmarClassInstanceFromPreviousSelectMany.BEmem.SoldDate.Value.Month)) + 1d)) / 12d
        : 1d
    : 1d } );'
```

2nd statement:

```
            'Func<IQueryable<Emar>, object> customSelectManyDelegate =

           await CSharpScript
             .EvaluateAsync<Func<IQueryable<Emar>, object>>(methodArgumentStringContainingSelectStatement, options);

         resultOfSelect =  customSelectManyDelegate(instanceContainingSelectMethod as IQueryable<Emar>);'
```

Comment: Really, to receive a useful answer, you should add context to your question. Please show a [mcve]. Where did you create these types? Obviously the compiler generated two different types (hence two different names). But without the code that led the compiler to do this, we can't say anything about it.

Comment: It's unclear why any of these tags are on the question, except maybe Roslyn.  You might be using EF and linq, but what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: afaik the compiler generates anonymous types _per assembly_. So maybe you created them in different assemblies?

Comment: Maybe you could tell us why you think they are the same? The 'Name' and 'FullName' are different, so why would you expect them to be identical?

Comment: @RenéVogt I might be wrong, but I thought it was actually *per module*; now granted... most assemblies only have 1 module, but...

Comment: @MarcGravell well I don't know it down to these details, a distinction between modules and assemblies was never necessary in may all-day work ;)

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: @RenéVogt Hmmm, just looking at your answers. A question comes to mind. Does the anonymous type returned by EvaluateAsync(Roslyn scripting API) in 2nd statement and anonymous type returned by select 1st statement make them from two different assemblies even though both are in the same piece of code?

Comment: You are using CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync.  Each evaluation in C# script is logically its own assembly.  Anonymous types are (by implementation not specification) unique per assembly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anonymous types are really only meant to be used in the context of a single method, or *maybe* in some reflection scenarios where just the shape is important, not the type.

So: asking why the type is different *is already breaking the intent of the language feature*. As for *why* they are different: probably different assemblies or modules. This applies in particular in web projects where the views are compiled later than the main code.

But: don't rely on this equality, basically. It isn't guaranteed. If you care what the type is (and what it is equal to), then your options include:

- declaring a formal type of your own, and using it - best option
- using value-tuples (`ValueTuple<...>`, but with first-class language support including pseudo-names that propagate from callee to caller, but not from caller to callee)
- using tuples (`Tuple<...>`)

Using anonymous types doesn't really appear in the list.

Comment: Could my reply/question to @RenéVogt  possibly be the difference.

Comment: @K.CarterSr. kinda hard to say without a concrete repro, but once again I'd emphasize that it *isn't worth knowing* : you aren't *meant* to care about type equality if you (by definition) already can't care about the type

Comment: Marc Gravell. I'm Marking this as accepted even though @René Vogt said it first and I don't see anyway to mark a comment as accepted.  Matt Warren anwser explained in more detail. Thanks  Matt Warren.  Also,  Marc, take a look a my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056318/is-there-anyway-to-execute-this-expression-and-get-the-actual-value-not-as-objec . It's also in the same code, and related.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Warren wrote this comment:

> You are using CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync. Each evaluation in C# script is logically its own assembly. Anonymous types are (by implementation not specification) unique per assembly. – Matt Warren Mar 8 '19 at 19:17